# How can the Authorization header be propagated in Quarkus Apps with the MicroProfile Rest Client?

Tags: quarkus, microprofile

I have two microservices implemented with Quarkus 1.5.2.Final with endpoints that are protected with @RolesAllowed("user"). The endpoints work when I call them directly with a valid token.

When I use the MicroProfile Rest Client (synchronous mode) to invoke the second microservice, the Authorization header is missing.

According to the MicroProfile spec (https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-1.3/microprofile-rest-client-1.3.html) the following setting should do the trick:
org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.propagateHeaders=Authorization

However it doesn't work. I also tried these without success.
"mp.rest.client.propagateHeaders=Authorization", "resteasy.role.based.security=true" and "quarkus.smallrye-jwt.enabled=true".

When I add the header manually to the Rest Client it works, but my understanding was this should be done automatically.

Do I do anything wrong or could this be an issue with the MicroProfile version embedded in Quarkus 1.5.2.Final?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a sample application: https://github.com/IBM/cloud-native-starter/tree/master/security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phillip Krüger answered the question. All that needed to be added was this setting in the service which is invoked by another service.

resteasy.role.based.security=true

Code is here: https://github.com/IBM/cloud-native-starter/blob/d30b084eeddcebf793037bea07244fe20917caa3/security/articles-secure/src/main/resources/application.properties#L9

Answer (score 1):

As per the spec, for the `mp.rest.client.propagateHeaders` property to work you need to have `@RegisterClientHeaders` specified on the interface that defines the external service.

Comment: Thanks Ken. Sorry for late response (vacation). RegisterClientHeaders doesn't work either unfortunately. https://github.com/IBM/cloud-native-starter/blob/274694d97d8751e9babdb4a7a456737ab9cd50b6/security/web-api-secure/src/main/java/com/ibm/webapi/ArticlesService.java#L13 and https://github.com/IBM/cloud-native-starter/blob/274694d97d8751e9babdb4a7a456737ab9cd50b6/security/web-api-secure/src/main/resources/application.properties#L19

Comment: I also tried @RegisterRestClient without success :(

Comment: @NiklasHeidloff read this: https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-1.2.1/microprofile-rest-client-1.2.1.html#_jax_rs

Comment: Is it possible the header is not called "Authorization" but something else?

Comment: No, it has the right name. When I add it manually to the request it works.

Comment: Did you tried with `ClientRequestFilter`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64121292/5078874